# How to find the key of a dictionary when the value is a list of objects in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I want to find the corresponding key when I have a list of objects as a value. 
Suppose I have a Dictionary,

```
 Dictionary<string, List<object>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();
```

I know I could do something like,

```
foreach (var item in dict)
{
    foreach (var subItem in item.Value)
    {
        if (subItem.Equals(foo))
        {
              Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
        }
     }
}
```

But this takes a lot of time I have a huge data set. Is there a faster solution to this?

I know that the normal way of finding keys given the value, using LINQ is something like:

```
var keysWithMatchingValues = dict.Where(p => p.Value == myObject).Select(p => p.Key);
```

I am looking for a similar solution in my situation.

Comment: Using LINQ isn't changing the fundamental algorithm being used here.  If this is too slow then you'll need to adjust your data structure to one that doesn't require you to look through every single item to find the data you want.

Comment: LINQ isn't more performant most times, but it's often easier to write correct and readable code with LINQ. If no duplciates are possible i'd use a `HashSet<T>` instead of the list. If you know what type it is i'd use that type instead of object.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Dictionary has a `ContainsValue` method which would be more elegant than looping or linqing, but it is still linear time.

Comment: You could maybe store values as keys and keys as values? If values are not unique then you could use - `List<KeyValuePair<object,string>>`. Also, you could make a smaller object, instead of passing whole.

Comment: You could maintain a second dictionary (`Dictionary<object, List<string>>`) where the key is the object and the list of strings contains the keys from the first dictionary that contain the object in its list.

Comment: @Crowcoder: how does `ContainsValue` help to find an object in a list that is the value?

Comment: @Tim Shmelter How doesn't it? Yes you still have to iterate the list but ContainsValue would eliminate a nested loop.

Comment: @Matt Wilko gotcha. Yes, I totally spaced. Apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ isn't more performant most times, but it's often easier to write correct and readable code with LINQ. If no duplicate values are possible i'd use a `HashSet<T>` instead of the list. If you know what type it is i'd use that type instead of object.

The LINQ version of your code would be....

1. with `List.Contains`:

   ```
   List<string> keysWithValue =  dict
       .Where(kv => kv.Value.Contains(foo))
       .Select(kv => kv.Key);
       .ToList();
   ```
2. or `Enumerable.Any`:

   ```
   List<string> keysWithValue =  dict
       .Where(kv => kv.Value.Any(v => foo.Equals(v)))
       .Select(kv => kv.Key);
       .ToList();
   ```

But as mentioned this wouldn't be more efficient. One way to improve performance would be to use a [`Lookup<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=vs.110).aspx). If the dictionary doesn't change you only need to create it once:

```
var valueToKeyLookup = dict  // make it an instance field, so that you don't have to create it always
    .SelectMany(kv => kv.Value
        .Distinct()
        .Select(v => new {Key = kv.Key, Value = v})
    )
    .ToLookup(x => x.Value, x => x.Key);
```

Now the remaining code is very concise and efficient:

```
List<string> allKeysWithFoo = valueToKeyLookup[foo].ToList();
```

Note that this will even work if no list contains that value, then the result will be an empty list.

Comment: @Thomas: yes, now it is, but at the cost of another collection so more memory

Comment: @Thomas: the cost of creating the lookup is expensive but looking things up in it is very fast.  if you need to look up multiple things in an unchanging dictionary, this would be much faster.

Comment: @MarkPeters Answer has changed after my comment ;)